# iPhone Share Button

Tags: ios

How can I recreate this, something found throughout native iPhone apps such as Safari and Photos.

[image]

I'm assuming it is pretty simple, I just don't even know what it is called so I'm having trouble finding out how.
It is usually reached using an action (or export or something) button.

Comment: looks like you are just having trouble finding the correct keyword to search for; because i seen this question before

Comment: @Cocoa Matters: Please stop adding inappropriate tags to questions. [xcode] is for questions _about_ Xcode. [ipad] and [iphone] are only applicable when the question is _specific_ to those pieces of hardware. [objective-c] is for when the question _contains_ code in, or _is about_, the Objective-C language.

Comment: @lulius Thanx for sharing the information for tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same functionality is called as [UIActionsheet](http://eureka.ykyuen.info/2010/04/14/iphone-uiactionsheet-example/). You can get plenty of examples for the same on SO itself.

Answer (score 1):

you are looking for whats called a UIActionSheet

check this out for more info
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

you have to create action sheet https://github.com/gpambrozio/BlockAlertsAnd-ActionSheets